# Finding a mapping reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $\overline{CF_{TM}}$

Tags: turing-machines, computability, context-free, reductions

I am trying to find a mapping reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $\overline{CF_{TM}}$, but I can't seem to find one.

Definitions:
$$\begin{align*}
CF_{TM} &= \left\{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{$M$ is a TM and $L(M)$ is context-free} \right\} \\
A_{TM} &= \left\{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid \text{$M$ is a TM and $w \in L(M)$} \right\}
\end{align*}$$

AFAIK the mapping reduction of the regular (i.e., not the complimentary) language is as follows: $\langle M,w \rangle \in A_{TM}$ if and only if we can construct a language $L$ which is context-free in the sense that $L(F((\langle M,w \rangle)))$ is context-free.

Comment: You write about a $L(F((\langle M, w \rangle)))$. What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: that if x exists in $A_{TM}$ then there should be a x in f(x) to make the reduction, when f(x) is CF. so i need to take language as a function of A_TM and make it an instance of $CF_{TM}$. i think i should've chosen the function to be for $a^2^n$ format, because if $A_{TM}$ accepts it then a* is regular and also a CFL, and if it doesn't accept then it is not a cfl. but my main problem is why the compliment. could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be recursively enumerable but not context-free (and, therefore, not empty). We only need the existence of such an $L$; the actual choice is immaterial. In addition, recall the empty set $\varnothing$ is context-free. The idea is to map to a TM which accepts $L$ in case $M$ accepts $w$ (i.e., $\langle M,w \rangle \in A_{TM}$) and to $\varnothing$ otherwise.

Given an instance $\langle M,w \rangle$ of $A_{TM}$, map it to the description $\langle S \rangle$, where $S$ is the TM which does the following:

> On input $w'$:
>
> 1. Run $M$ on $w$. If $M$ rejects, reject.
> 2. If $M$ accepts $w$, then accept if and only if $w' \in L$.

Note that, if $M$ does not halt on $w$, then $S$ does not halt either. Also, $w' \in L$ can be checked because $L$ is recursively enumerable (and $S$ need not halt in case that is false). We conclude that $L(S) = L$ if $\langle M, w \rangle \in A_{TM}$ and $L(S) = \varnothing$ (which is context-free) otherwise.

---

**An observation.** The trick behind 98% of these problems lies in understanding what you need to do (i.e., what I wrote in the first paragraph). The actual description for the instance you are reducing to (in this case, $\langle S \rangle$) might look tricky or esoteric at first sight, but it actually simply follows as a consequence once you have the right ideas in mind.